# Querying multiple partitions hive?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

How can I query multiple partitions of the same table in Hive? In the same command?

Something like ???

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE partition ='first_partition' and partition='second_partition'
```

Answer (score 9):

In Hive, partition is also a column, so in a query perspective, there is no difference. You can think it as a column.

if table `page_views` is partitioned on column `date`, the following query retrieves rows for just days between `2008-03-01` and `2008-03-31`.

```
SELECT page_views.*
FROM page_views
WHERE page_views.date >= '2008-03-01' AND page_views.date <= '2008-03-31'
```

In your case, you can use like

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE column_one ='first_partition' and column_two ='second_partition'
```

It will be more clear, if you give the table structure.